# Common ways to connect to odbc from python on windows?

Tags: python, windows, odbc, pywin32, pyodbc

What library should I use to connect to odbc from python on windows? Is there a good alternative for pywin32 when it comes to odbc?

I'm looking for something well-documented, robust, actively maintained, etc. [`pyodbc`](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc) looks good -- are there any others?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You already suggested **pyodbc**, and I am going to agree with you.

It has given me the least amount of issues in my experience; I've used [pymssql](http://pymssql.sourceforge.net/) and [adodbapi](http://adodbapi.sourceforge.net/), and when those threw exceptions/created issues, I swapped out the code and replaced it with pyodbc and it either fixed the problem, or gave better error messages so I could debug faster.

It's worth mentioning that I primarily use it to connect to **MSSQL Server** DBs.

Comment: But that pyodbc comes with the expectation of having an ODBC driver and setup in the machines where its been used and run. right? If we dont have odbc and just wanna rely on pure sql drivers thats available on the machines, what would you recommend?

Answer (score 18):

I use [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org) for all python database access. I highly recommend SQLAlchemy.

SA uses pyodbc under the hood when connecting to SQL server databases. It uses other DBAPI libraries to connect to other database, for instance cx_Oracle.

A simplistic example, using SQLAlchemy like you would normally use a DBAPI module:

```
import sqlalchemy

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:///database.db')
for r in engine.execute('SELECT * FROM T'):
    print(r.OneColumn, r.OtherColumn)
```

But the real value of SQLAlchemy lies in its [ORM](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/05/ormtutorial.html) and [SQL expression language](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/05/sqlexpression.html). Have a look, it is well worth the effort to learn to use.

Comment: SQLAlchemy made it very easy for me to switch between odbc and adodbapi without changing more than two lines of code.

Answer (score 7):

Another alternative is [pypyodbc](https://github.com/jiangwen365/pypyodbc/) which was written in pure Python. it can been seen as a re-implemenation of the pyodbc module – with only around 1800 lines code, which is good for maintenance.

Here's a [Hello World sample of accessing mssql in Python](https://github.com/jiangwen365/pypyodbc/wiki/A-Hello-World-script-of-pypyodbc).

Comment: But that pyodbc comes with the expectation of having an ODBC driver and setup in the machines where its been used and run. right? If we dont have odbc and just wanna rely on pure sql drivers thats available on the machines, what would you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

I use pyodbc at work and it has never failed me (we have varius dbs). It is robust and fast.

It is actively maintained and a python 3 version will come soon.

If you want "enterprise" software with payed support you can use [mxODBC](http://www.egenix.com/products/python/mxODBC/).

Comment: pyodbc not working for me on Windows python 3.1.2 :(

Comment: there is no official build for python 3 :( im waiting for one also. There is an unofficial that u have to build yourself

Comment: It fails for me too.  pyodbc comes with the expectation of having an ODBC driver and setup in the machines where its been used and run. right? If we dont have odbc and just wanna rely on pure sql drivers thats available on the machines, what would you recommend?

Comment: @Ak777 yes you need to install an odbc driver if you want to use pyodbc since pyodbc is just a wrapper for easy use of odbc. If you don't want to install odbc you could look into native libraries. For example for microsoft database you could use: pymssql. The best is to look at list of Included Dialects for sqlalchemy here https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects. This is how I found about pymssql.

Answer (score 1):

You can give [turbodbc](https://github.com/blue-yonder/turbodbc) a spin. Since version 1.1.1, it officially supports Windows. There's a good chance that it is faster than pyodbc for what you do.

Answer (score -4):

Python 3 is now supported by [pyodbc](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc)!

Comment: How is this a response? Doesn't address the OP question.