# Install MYSQLdb python module without MYSQL local install

Tags: python, mysql, windows

I'm trying to install MYSQLdb on a windows client.  The goal is, from the Windows client, run a python script that connects to a MySQL server on a LINUX client.  Looking at the setup code (and based on the errors I am getting when I try to run setup.py for mysqldb, it appears that I have to have my own version of MySQL on the windows box.  Is there a way (perhaps another module) that will let me accomplish this?  I need to have people on multiple boxes run a script that will interact with a MySQL database on a central server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a pure python implementation of the mysql client like

- [`pymysql`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=pymysql)
  (can be used as a dropin-replacement for MySQLdb by calling `pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()`)
- [`MySql-Connector`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-Connector)

Comment: MySql-Connector will run by itself and not require any local MySQL libraries?

Comment: Yes, both libraries run without need for the mysql libraries to be installed. They're also [supported by sqlalchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.pymysql) as dialects.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the entire MySQL database server, only the MySQL client libraries.

Comment: Which client libraries would I need?  I tried downloading them but they didn't work.  I double-checked and I ended up downloading the on for C code.  I don't see one for python.  I'm looking here, which might not be the right spot?  http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/

Comment: The C connector is the correct choice. You need to point the linker at the .lib files so it can't link against the DLL.

Comment: 'setup.py install' still failed with that connector installed.  It's looking for registry entries that this connector does not seem to be installing.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since I wrote python db code for windows...but I think something like this should still work.

If you're running the client only on windows machines, install the [pywin32 package](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/).  This should have an odbc module in it.

Using the windows control / management tools, create an odbc entry for either the user or the system.  In that entry, you'll give the connection parameter set a unique name, then select the driver (in this case MySQL), and populate the connection parameters (e.g. host name, etc.)  See [PyWin32 Documentation](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/contents.html) for some notes on the odbc module in pywin32.

Also, see this post: [Common ways to connect to odbc from python on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768312/common-ways-to-connect-to-odbc-from-python-on-windows/768330#768330).